# Show H1 by default in Magnolia WYSIWYG editor

Tags: magnolia

If there a site-wide way to force the WYSIWYG editor in Magnolia to show a select box with "Heading 1", "Heading 2", etc. before the Bold/Italics/Underline buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I created this helper method in a service.

```
public RichTextFieldBuilder extendRichText(RichTextFieldBuilder richTextFieldBuilder) {
    RichTextFieldDefinition richTextFieldDefinition = richTextFieldBuilder.definition();
    richTextFieldDefinition.setConfigJsFile("/.resources/ckeditor/config.js");
    richTextFieldBuilder.images(true);
    return richTextFieldBuilder;
}
```

Then created this file: `/.resources/ckeditor/config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = "Magnolia";
    config.toolbar_Magnolia = [
        { name: "styles",        items: [ "Format", "FontSize", "TextColor" ] },
        { name: "styles",        items: [ "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "SpecialChar" ] },
        { name: "paragraph",     items: [ "NumberedList", "BulletedList", "PasteFromWord" ] },
        { name: "objects",       items: [ "Image" ] },
        { name: "links",         items: [ "Link", "InternalLink", "DamLink", "Unlink" ] }
    ];
};
```

You may also need the format plugin for CKEditor.